# How to use Long data type in C?

Tags: java, c, rounding, long-integer

I'm a little confused as to how longs work in C.

If I ask for the maximum value of a long in Java I get a number in the quintillions.  If I ask for it in C, signed or unsigned, it's in the billions.

Java is built on C... so where is the difference coming from?

I've also tried representing literals with long long values, unsigned/signed long values and long int values.  None of them seem to handle numbers past the mid-billions.  Why?  Am I making a mistake?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C standard defines `long` to be at least as large as `int`. The actual size is implementation dependent.  This is not the case for Java, in which `long` is required to be 64 bits long.

The C99 standard defines fixed size integer types like `int64_t` defined in `stdint.h` that you can use if you need fixed size integers on all platforms.

Comment: Just to add a comment: It usually depends on the bits of your operating system, but of course the doesn't have to be the case.

Comment: Can I use a 64bit long in the standard C library?

Comment: @ghostsoldier23 You can use 64 long for libraries which take 64-bit values, usually requiring your program be compiled as 64-bit e.g. when `size_t` is 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

C also has the `long long` type. That one is guaranteed to be at least 64 bit.

Comment: C99 defines `long long int` to be _at least_ be able to hold 64 bit signed integers and greater than the size of `long int`. It isn't necessarily 64 bit.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari, right, I was not precise enough, thanks, changed.

Comment: @Mehrdad: you said, in effect, that the size of `long long int` must be strictly greater than the size of `long int`; is that correct?  Surely, a conforming implementation can provide `long long int` the same size as `long int`; the size of `long long int` cannot be less than the size of `long int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler not strictly. Greater as in ">=" which is what I wrote in my answer--but `long int` should at least be 32 bits and `long long int` should be at least 64 bits. If a conforming implementation is about to use the same size for both, it can, however, both should be at least 64 bits in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with bigger numbers you can use the GNU MP Bignum Library here:
http://gmplib.org/
The numbers and the precision is only limited by available memory of the machine that it runs on.